# Flash Builder best practice for working on multiple versions of a project

Tags: flash-builder

I have a large Flash Builder project that is part of a much larger (.net) solution. I typically have, for the entire project, a forward dev branch going, as well one or more bug fix branches. What is the best way to set this up in Flash Builder, given that Flash Builder does NOT want to import an new project (bug fix branch) that has the same name as an existing (forward dev branch) project?

Comment: possibly useful? -- http://www.arpitonline.com/blog/2008/04/19/on-flashflex-build-systems-and-application-versioning/

Comment: I'm trying to understand what up. Are you using a configured SVN for this project? Because, it's a well know system to come back or forward in revisions of the project.

Comment: Yes, I am using SVN, but we have multiple active branches. What I do right now is use Flash Builder's Workspaces. I have a separate Workspace for each active branch, and I switch between them as necessary to work on different branches. The downside is that I can't open the Forward Dev branch and the QA branch side by side with this approach.

Comment: I'd create different workspaces for the branches. If you dont need a branch, you can delete the project from it, or simply delete the workspace folder.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is understand the workspace limitations. Eclipse doesn't accept projects with the same name, is an old problem. I could say you, isn't only eclipse, but a lot IDEs have such problem and bugs about it.

We want a create a project, production, what is the current stable version, at least one bug test and the next project version. Then, in this Eclipse case, you should name it to something like `ProjectNameProd`, `ProjectNameBugFix` and `ProjectNameNextVersion`. It's also good for browser files by path, as you have the folder saying what is inside.

You can put all in one SVN or GIT repo, or create one repository for each one of these contents. Then, configure the Eclipse/Flash Builder to use SVN, [follow this well explained](http://www.flashmagazine.com/tutorials/detail/setting_up_subversion_with_adobe_flash_builder_4/).

Another, not well, approach is set one project and all your targets but it is really a mess to organize and keep things separated.

Hope help you.